# Find and extract year within sentence for each cell in R

Tags: r, date, dataframe, text, extract

I have a large dataframe of 22641 obs. and 12 variables. 
The first column `"year"` includes extracted values from satellite images in the format below.

```
1_1_1_1_LT05_127024_19870517_00005ff8aac6b6bf60bc
```

From this format, I only want to keep the date which in this case is `19870517` and format it as date (so two different things).  Usually, I use the `regex` to extract the words that I want, but here the date is different for each cell and I have no idea how to replace the above text with only the date. Maybe the way to do this is to search by position within the sentence but I do not know how.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear what the "date is different in each cell" means but if it means that the value of the date is different and it is always the 7th field then either of (1) or (2) will work.  If it either means that it consists of 8 consecutive digits anywhere in the text or 8 consecutive digits surrounded by _ anywhere in the text then see (3).

**1)** Assuming the input `DF` shown in reproducible form in the Note at the end use `read.table` to read `year`, pick out the 7th field and then convert it to `Date` class.  No packages are used.

```
transform(read.table(text = DF$year, sep = "_")[7],
  year = as.Date(as.character(V7), "%Y%m%d"), V7 = NULL)
##         year
## 1 1987-05-17
```

**2)** Another alternative is `separate` in tidyr.  0.8.2 or later is needed.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

DF %>%
  separate(year, c(rep(NA, 6), "year"), extra = "drop") %>%
  mutate(year = as.Date(as.character(year), "%Y%m%d"))

##         year
## 1 1987-05-17
```

**3)** This assumes that the date is the only sequence of 8 digits in the `year` field use this or if we know it is surrounded by _ delimiters then the regular expression `"_(\\d{8})_"` can be used instead.

```
library(gsubfn)

transform(DF, 
  year = do.call("c", strapply(DF$year, "\\d{8}", ~ as.Date(x, "%Y%m%d"))))

##         year
## 1 1987-05-17
```

### Note

```
DF <- data.frame(year = "1_1_1_1_LT05_127024_19870517_00005ff8aac6b6bf60bc",
 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: thank you for your response and apologies for my English. The value of date differs not the number of digits. The No3. solution looks better for my case because date is not always the 7th field. However, the proposed solution just removes my entire column and I do not see the reason why. The first 2 solutions work fine for the observations where date is the 7th place.

Comment: The question did not provide reproducible input or preciely define what output was desired so the answer here provided the input reproducibly in the Note and the body of the answer shows what output you get for that input.  In (3) if you don't want to overwrite `year` just call it something else such as `date`, e.g.`transform(DF, date = do.call...)`

Comment: @G.Grothendieck The end part of the string looks like a guid.  Your #3 (more generalizable solution) may have a hiccup if this includeds a random string of `_00005ff19841112460bc` instead of `_00005ff8aac6b6bf60bc`

Comment: @TylerRinker The answer already states that it assumes that *the date is the only sequence of 8 digits in the year field* and gives an alternative regular expression for the alternative assumption that the date is 8 digits but surrouned by _ marks.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this will generalize to your whole data but maybe:

```
gsub(
    '(^(?:.*?[^0-9])?)(\\d{8})((?:[^0-9].*)?$)', 
    '\\2', 
    '1_1_1_1_LT05_127024_19870517_00005ff8aac6b6bf60bc', 
    perl = TRUE
)

## [1] "19870517"
```

This uses group capturing and throws away anything but bounded 8 digit strings.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sub` to extract the data string and `as.Date` to convert it into R's date format:

```
 as.Date(sub(".+?([0-9]+)_[^_]+$", "\\1", txt), "%Y%m%d")
 # [1] "1987-05-17"
```

where `txt <- "1_1_1_1_LT05_127024_19870517_00005ff8aac6b6bf60bc"`